# Hive: Can't select one random match on right table in left outer join

Tags: hive, outer-join

EDIT - I don't care about the skewness or things being slow.  I found out that the slowness was more so caused by a many times many join on many matches in my left outer join... Please skip down to the bottom.

<strike>I have an issue of a skewed table, that is, many more keys than other keys to join.  My problem is that I have more than one key with many appearances in the rows.</strike>

Stats on this table and table I am joining with:
Larger table: totalSize=47431500000, numRows=509500000, rawDataSize=47022050000 21052 distinct keys 
Smaller table: totalSize=1154984612, numRows=13780692, rawDataSize=1141203920 AND 39313 distinct keys

The smaller table also has repeated rows of keys. The other challenge is that I need to randomly select a matching key from the smaller table.

What I have tried so far:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=1155mb;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table AS SELECT * FROM (
select * from larger_table as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN smaller_table as b 
on a.key = b.key 
ORDER BY RAND()
)b;
```

It has been running for a day now.

I thought about manually doing something like [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Skewed+Join+Optimization) but, I have more than one key that there are a ton of, so I would have to make a bunch of tables and merge them.  Which I can do if that is my only option :O

But I wanted to reach out to you all on SO.

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT June 20th
I found to try:
    set hive.optimize.skewjoin = true;
    set hive.skewjoin.key = 200000;
I had already created a few separate tables to separate and join up the highest appearing keys, such that now the highest appearing key in the rest was 200k.  Running the query to join the rest now took 25 minutes, finished all tasks successfully, according to the job tracker on the web interface.  On the command line in the Hive shell, it is still sitting there, and when I go to check, the table does not exist.

**EDIT #2 After a lot of reading and trying out a lot of sql hive code... the 1 solution that should have worked in theory did not work, specifically the order by rand() never even happened...

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table AS SELECT * FROM (
select * from larger_table as a 
JOIN 
(SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by key order by rand() )
from smaller_table) as b
on a.key = b.key 
and b.row_num=1
)b;
```

In the results it is being matched with the first row, not a rand() row at all..

Any other options or anything I did incorrectly here?

Comment: Any chance you could some how refactor the schema? (split tables etc..)

Comment: @DarioOO - I tried with one month (vs one year), and it brought the rows down by a factor of 10.  I tried the above again, and the same thing happened:  Hadoop web interface job tracker showed the status to completion, on the hive shell the sql is hanging as if it is still in progress, and the table does not exist.

Comment: I mean, organizing the tables so that outer join is no longer required. Change the ER- schema in some way could be very feasible, also RANDOM is bad, try to keep a random list somwhere and use it as random lookup to access ORDERED elements, profile that and see if that is fast or slow. Also you should keep in mind that probably you have a Terabyte of data and you are doing an operation with a cost of possibly O(n^2). Plus the bandwith for intra-process communication on server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DarioOO after some profiling - I realize that taking out rand() then the join only takes a few minutes!  Another issue though that I have discovered is the resulting table is many more rows I would expect (126 times more!).  I would expect the number of rows to be equal to the table on the left.  Is there any reason this could happen?

Comment: Ok I think [I found an answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713932/left-outer-join-gives-extra-rows-problem)  - that I need to do a distinct on select, because it is perhaps matching to every single repeated thing in the right table.  I will answer my own question with a summary of results when I accomplish my mission

Comment: nevermind, I tried using a subquery to return one random row that matches on the key but the problem is a subquery can only return one column, not a whole row of columns (Which is what I need to join on). and I don't want all the matches from the right table, just one.  back to the drawing board

Comment: False alarm.. still not working.  Please my notes in the original post under EDIT #2