# Second left outer join not returning the correct row count using Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am working with 3 dataframes and am joining them together starting with the `network` dataframe and joining the `organization` dataframe to it creating a new dataframe using a left outer join matching on the `OrgID` column.  Then using the new dataframe and joining the `asn` dataframe to it performing an left outer join uing the `OrgID` for the join.

Dataframes:

```
network.show(5)
+--------------------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|           NetHandle|    OrgID|          Parent|             NetName|            NetRange|     NetType|Comment|            RegDate|            Updated|Source|
+--------------------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------ +
|NET-69-150-149-184-1|C00868859|NET-69-148-0-0-1|SBC06915014918429...|69.150.149.184 - ...|reassignment|   null|2004-07-23 00:00:00|2004-07-23 00:00:00|  ARIN|
| NET-69-224-242-40-1|C00868860|NET-69-224-0-0-1|SBC06922424204029...|69.224.242.40 - 6...|reassignment|   null|2004-07-23 00:00:00|2004-07-23 00:00:00|  ARIN|
| NET-170-55-30-176-1|  CC-3105|NET-170-55-0-0-1|FPLFI-CROWNSCFSW-...|170.55.30.176 - 1...|reassignment|   null|2018-03-26 00:00:00|2018-03-26 00:00:00|  ARIN|
| NET-69-224-249-24-1|C00868862|NET-69-224-0-0-1|SBC06922424902429...|69.224.249.24 - 6...|reassignment|   null|2004-07-23 00:00:00|2004-07-23 00:00:00|  ARIN|
| NET-69-29-107-152-1|C02309164| NET-69-29-0-0-1|   CTEL-CITZENS-BANK|69.29.107.152 - 6...|reassignment|   null|2009-09-03 00:00:00|2009-09-03 00:00:00|  ARIN|
+--------------------+---------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+
only showing top 5 rows

organization.show(5)
+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
|    OrgID|             OrgName|CanAllocate|              Street|        City|State/Prov|Country|PostalCode|            RegDate|            Updated|OrgAdminHandle|OrgTechHandle|OrgAbuseHandle|Source|
+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
|C05709929|      Allen Matthews|       null|           PO Box399|Simpsonville|        MD|     US|     21150|2015-05-02 00:00:00|2015-05-02 00:00:00|          null|         null|          null|  ARIN|
|C07025896|BIANCA BIANCA-180...|       null|     Private Address|       Plano|        TX|     US|     75075|2018-07-19 00:00:00|2018-07-19 00:00:00|          null|         null|          null|  ARIN|
|  TBL-353|TEST BVOIP COMPAN...|       null|225 W RANDOLPH UN...|        CHGO|        IL|     US|     99774|2015-05-02 00:00:00|2015-05-02 00:00:00|  SHRES56-ARIN| SHRES56-ARIN|  SHRES56-ARIN|  ARIN|
|  AIM-109|ASHLEY INDUSTRIAL...|       null|      951 2ND AVE SE|     OELWEIN|        IA|     US|     50662|2015-05-02 00:00:00|2015-05-02 00:00:00|  MARTZ16-ARIN| MARTZ16-ARIN|  MARTZ16-ARIN|  ARIN|
|C07025664|Brodynt Global Se...|       null|2500 William Park...|    Brampton|        ON|     CA|   L6S 5M9|2018-07-19 00:00:00|2018-07-19 00:00:00|          null|         null|          null|  ARIN|
+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
only showing top 5 rows

asn.show(5)
+--------+---------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+
|ASHandle|    OrgID|      ASName|ASNumber|            RegDate|             Comment|            Updated|Source|
+--------+---------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+
|     AS0|     IANA| IANA-RSVD-0|       0|2002-09-13 00:00:00|Reserved - May be...|2002-09-13 00:00:00|  ARIN|
|     AS1|  LPL-141|      LVLT-1|       1|2001-09-20 00:00:00|                null|2018-02-20 00:00:00|  ARIN|
|     AS2|UNIVER-19|    UDEL-DCN|       2|1991-01-10 00:00:00|                null|2012-06-21 00:00:00|  ARIN|
|     AS3|    MIT-2|MIT-GATEWAYS|       3|1970-01-01 00:00:00|                null|2010-09-27 00:00:00|  ARIN|
|     AS4|   USC-32|      ISI-AS|       4|1984-02-22 00:00:00|                null|2012-03-13 00:00:00|  ARIN|
+--------+---------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

These are the counts of the 3 spark dataframes:

```
network.count()
3418057
organization.count()
3660886
asn.count()
27745
```

The first join seems to work as you can see I have the same count as the network dataframe `3418057`:

```
df = network.join(organization, ["OrgID"], 'leftouter')
df.show(2)
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
|  OrgID|           NetHandle|          Parent|             NetName|            NetRange|     NetType|Comment|            RegDate|            Updated|Source|             OrgName|CanAllocate|           Street|        City|State/Prov|Country|PostalCode|            RegDate|            Updated|OrgAdminHandle|OrgTechHandle|OrgAbuseHandle|Source|
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
| 3DIMEN|  NET-199-33-182-0-1| NET-199-0-0-0-0|             NET-3DP|199.33.182.0 - 19...|  assignment|   null|1994-01-11 00:00:00|1994-06-21 00:00:00|  ARIN|                null|       null|             null|Philadelphia|        PA|     US|     19104|1994-01-11 00:00:00|2011-09-24 00:00:00|    JM143-ARIN|   JM143-ARIN|    JM143-ARIN|  ARIN|
|AA-1166|NET6-2001-1890-13...|NET6-2001-1890-1|ATTW-2001-1890-13...|2001:1890:131E:6D00:|reallocation|   null|2016-02-29 00:00:00|2016-02-29 00:00:00|  ARIN|AMERICAN ACCESSORIES|       null|3100 BANDINI BLVD|      VERNON|        CA|     US|     40456|2016-02-29 00:00:00|2016-02-29 00:00:00|   DURAZ5-ARIN|  DURAZ5-ARIN|   DURAZ5-ARIN|  ARIN|
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

**Edit:corrected typo**

```
print(df.count())
[Stage 52:====================================================> (193 + 7) / 200]3418057
```

But when I use the new dataframe and perform a left outer join with the `asn` dataframe I should get a count of `3418057` but I am getting a count of `1661797`:

```
df1 = df.join(asn, ["OrgID"], 'leftouter')
df1.show(2)
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+--------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  OrgID|           NetHandle|          Parent|             NetName|            NetRange|     NetType|Comment|            RegDate|            Updated|Source|             OrgName|CanAllocate|           Street|        City|State/Prov|Country|PostalCode|            RegDate|            Updated|OrgAdminHandle|OrgTechHandle|OrgAbuseHandle|Source|ASHandle|ASName|ASNumber|RegDate|Comment|Updated|Source|
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+--------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 3DIMEN|  NET-199-33-182-0-1| NET-199-0-0-0-0|             NET-3DP|199.33.182.0 - 19...|  assignment|   null|1994-01-11 00:00:00|1994-06-21 00:00:00|  ARIN|                null|       null|             null|Philadelphia|        PA|     US|     19104|1994-01-11 00:00:00|2011-09-24 00:00:00|    JM143-ARIN|   JM143-ARIN|    JM143-ARIN|  ARIN|    null|  null|    null|   null|   null|   null|  null|
|AA-1166|NET6-2001-1890-13...|NET6-2001-1890-1|ATTW-2001-1890-13...|2001:1890:131E:6D00:|reallocation|   null|2016-02-29 00:00:00|2016-02-29 00:00:00|  ARIN|AMERICAN ACCESSORIES|       null|3100 BANDINI BLVD|      VERNON|        CA|     US|     40456|2016-02-29 00:00:00|2016-02-29 00:00:00|   DURAZ5-ARIN|  DURAZ5-ARIN|   DURAZ5-ARIN|  ARIN|    null|  null|    null|   null|   null|   null|  null|
+-------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+--------+------+--------+-------+-------+-------+------+
only showing top 2 rows

print(df1.count())
[Stage 70:==================================================>   (187 + 7) / 200]4987448
```

This dataframe should have a count of `3418057` and not `4987448`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The second query performs right outer join on asn - there is no obvious reason why it should return exact count of the left hand side. The natural invariant is that it should have at least `asn` rows - which is satisfied.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo it should be leftouter @user10465355 let me change that.

Comment: OK. So now your query  returns 4987448 which is >= 3418057 (count of rows on LHS). Once again nothing unusual, unless `COUNT(DISTINCT OrgID) = COUNT(*)` for both LHS and RHS of the JOIN.

Comment: So all I want to do is add values from asn to df matching on the orgid column and fill null for the rest.  There should not be more than what is on the left side which is df.

Comment: Take a look at [LEFT OUTER JOIN (gives extra rows) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713932)

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing.  I tested it out in impala and it worked.  select count(*) as count from `analytics`.arin_network n 
left outer join (select  distinct orgid from `analytics`.arin_organization) o on o.`orgid` = n.`orgid` left outer join (select distinct orgid from `analytics`.arin_asn) a on o.`orgid` = a.`orgid`  Thank you @user10465355